# Failed migration in tests using Spring Boot with Flyway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

My spring boot app starts correctly, but tests fails. I've just added to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
       <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
       <version>6.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

My spring boot version: `2.3.1.RELEASE`

I spent 5 hours on looking for information but I can't resolve it.

I get this error: `Constraint "ANIMAL_PROFILE_PK" already exists;`

Migration:

```
(
    id varchar not null
        constraint user_auth_data_pk
            primary key,
    email varchar not null unique,
    pass varchar,
    token varchar,
    confirm boolean not null
);

create table animal_profile
(
    id varchar not null
        constraint animal_profile_pk
            primary key
            references user_auth_data(id),
    name varchar not null,
    type varchar not null,
    photo_url varchar unique not null,
    active boolean not null
);
```

Comment: How do your migrations look like? The error says that you are trying to add a Constraint that alreday exists

Comment: As I said before - it works correctly when I run it normally on localhost. I've added script.

Comment: Whats the name of the migration file?

Comment: V1__init_tables.sql

Comment: how does your test look like?